# How to check sharepoint group email users?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-email

I have my sharepoint site "Group1", and in the site there is an email Group1@company.onmicrosoft.com how can I see which users are receiving the email for that email? I am the owner and site admin for the sharepoint, but I cant find the place where that is specified.

My site has multiple owners, yet only a few received the email it seems. Where can I look the people associated to the email?

Comment: You can check it with your global administrator or user management administrator. You can see these details in office 365 admin portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Office 365 admin center using the below URL:

https://admin.microsoft.com/Adminportal/Home?source=applauncher#/groups

- Click on the **Group** from the left panel.
- Select your group from the group dashboard and double click on it.
- In the right-side panel dialog box click on the "Members"
- Below you can see the **members** of the that group

Example:

[image: Office 365 Group Members Details]

Notes:

- Whenever we create a modern site in SharePoint online or team from Microsoft Teams, an office 365 group will be created automatically.